# accessing HttpContext.Request in a controller's constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, controllers

I'm following this [ASP.NET MVC tutorial from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs):

My code is slightly different, where I'm trying to access `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` in the controller's constructor.

```
namespace SCE.Controllers.Application
{
    public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationController()
        {
            bool usuario = HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;
        }           
    }
}
```

The problem is that `HttpContext` is always null.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null ControllerContext in my custom controller inheriting from BaseController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236273/null-controllercontext-in-my-custom-controller-inheriting-from-basecontroller)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Controller is instantiated significantly prior to the point where the Index action is invoked, and at the moment of construction HttpContext is indeed unavailable. What's wrong with referencing it in your controller method `Index`?

Comment: only with DI in place controller constructors contain code and typically it is just one line _repository = repository

Answer (score 116):

instead of putting your `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` in Controller level you should put it in Controller Base class that will be inherited in all of your controller with an override method of OnActionExecuting() method.

In your Controller  base you should have

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx) {
        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
        ViewData["IsAuthenticated"] = HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

and all your Controller should inherit the BaseController class

```
public class ApplicationController : BaseController
```

now you should get the `ViewData["IsAuthenticated"]` in your Master page.

#### Edit

With the link you have given, and relating to what you have done, your `ApplicationController` is a Page Controller, not a Base Controller. In the example, `ApplicationController` is a Base Controller that is inherited by the `HomeController` but what you have done is you are placing the Action method inside your base controller which is the `ApplicationController` so your Action Index method will not be invoked when you call any page (Index page) that is not from the ApplicationController.

Comment: I had to change `Public` to `Protected` to make it work in my code, because of the error: _cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member_

Comment: I would think you'd want to override `OnActionExecuting`, which occurs before the `Action` code runs, rather than `OnActionExecuted` which happens after -- so you have access to `ViewData` (or whatever) in your method

Comment: You seem to be overriding `OnActionExecuting` but calling `base.OnActionExecuted` in the implementation. This looks like a typo to me.

Comment: oh, yeah.. nice catch.. I've changed the overridden method to `OnActionExecuting` instead of `OnActionExecuted` and that part wasn't changed.  Thanks

Comment: Should `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext ctx)` be  `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)` ?

Answer (score 60):

I would suggest you use:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Just remember `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is threadstatic, but if you don't use additional thread the solution works.

Comment: I believe that this post is the correct answer, the rest are  subject to best practices, personal preferences and task at hand.

Comment: I wonder why `Controller.HttpContext` isn't implemented using this

Comment: An gotcha for me. Mistaking httpContext property of the controller for HttpContext.Current

Answer (score 11):

The solution of this problem is to create an override method of Initialize by passing RequestContext object.

```
public class ChartsController : Controller
{
     bool isAuthed = false;
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
          isAuthed =true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]With the answer I am posting here, you **cannot access IsAuthenticated**, but you can access some stuffs related to HttpContextRequest (see in image),

I needed session value in constructor.

You can use IHttpContextAccessor as below:

```
public ABCController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)   
{
     //do you stuff with httpContextAccessor,  

     // This gives session value
     string abc = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Abc");
}
```

and in startup.cs, you need to configure,

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get the **HttpContext** using **IHttpContextAccessor** injected into class constructor. Before doing so, you will need first to register the corresponding service to the service container in **Startup.cs** class or **Program.cs** such as below.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // Startup.cs

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // Program.cs
```

Right after that, you can inject the IHttpContextAccessor interface in whererever method or class constructor.

```
 private bool isAuthenticated { get; set; }

    public ConstructorName(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        var context = accessor.HttpContext;

        isAuthenticated = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```