# Seems No Controllers Recognized by my controller factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, controller-factory

I want to create a controllerfactory with Autofac but I've got null reference instance error in this line : `string ctrName = contr.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()`  when I run my project.

This is my `controller factory`:

```
internal class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> _controllerMap;

    public ControllerFactory()
    {
        List<IController> lstControllers = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IController>().ToList();
        _controllerMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>>();

        foreach (Controller contr in lstControllers)
        {
            string ctrName = contr.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();  //iv got null instance error in this line
            _controllerMap.Add(ctrName, c => contr);
        }
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {

        if (_controllerMap.ContainsKey(controllerName))
        {
            return _controllerMap[controllerName](requestContext);
        }
        else
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(controllerName);
    }
}
```

and this is my appstart:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.Register(s => new ControllerFactory()).As<IControllerFactory>();


        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));


        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Error reason is clear: `ControllerContext` of my foreach item is null...but why? I have controller in my solution:

```
   public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

}
```

**Update:** I inspected debugger on foreach..the item type is `WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController` means exactly my home controller but controller context of mt item is null !!!

[image]

Comment: The `ControllerContext` is only valid during an HTTP request.

Comment: Break point so you can inspect `contr.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values` first of all to see what is in it. Secondly, do you have two `HomeController`?

Comment: @RagingCain no i dont have two ...i inspected break point and controller context of foreach item was null..and there was just one item in lstControllers "WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController" but controller context of that is null

Comment: @ImanSalehi Can you add a screenshot of the properties of said object, it might be that "Controller" is the invalid key to reference said object. Perhaps it's supposed to be "Home". There is some automapping magic for controllers.

Comment: @RagingCain https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYyjQ.jpg

Comment: @DavidG so What is your suggestion

Comment: Don't use `ControllerContext` outside of an HTTP request! You might be OK inside `CreateController` method.

Answer (score 1):

> This means the earliest point at which you can access the
>   ControllerContext property is by overriding the Execute or Initialize
>   method (but calling base.Execute or base.Initialize first):

```
protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
{
  base.Execute(requestContext);

  // .ControllerContext is available from this point forward.
}

protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
  base.Initialize(requestContext);

  // .ControllerContext is available from this point forward.
}
```

> The latter (Initialize) is the absolute earliest point at which you
>   can use the ControllerContext property, unless you handled the
>   assignment yourself, which is not recommended (as parts of the
>   framework will be dependent on having that property assigned to at
>   that time).

Source: [Null ControllerContext in my custom controller inheriting from BaseController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236273/null-controllercontext-in-my-custom-controller-inheriting-from-basecontroller)

You are going to have to `map` your `Controllers` elsewhere based on this new information.

Comment: TNX @Raging. but your source was not useful for me because i thimk my controller factory class is different with that, it have some properties that i dont have and it doesnt seem like have same type of class with mine . unfortunately there is not any complex sample about (controller factory...icontroller factory or default controller factory..) in any where. according my search, every body use this by their own solution. im completely  confused a bout it